# Python multiprocessing returns nothing

Tags: python

Multiprocessing Process class example in python documentary seem to return None. I copy pasted the example and run it, but it returns only ">>>" instead of printing 'hello', name. Tested in 2.7.11 and 3.5.1. I must be missing something obvious here, but can't figure out what.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

--Edit--
It works in Linux Ubuntu 14.04. Not in Windows 7.
--Edit-- Seems that the main issue is that whether it is run from IDLE or from file. Works when run from file.

Comment: I cut/paste your code into `idle` and I get what you got. If I put it into a file and execute the file I get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer that I missed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention the `>>>` prompt, it sounds like you are running the example in the interactive interpreter?
In that case, the `if __name__ == "__main__"` line will never evaluate to `True` and thus never run the code you want. You can read about this in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts).

Try either saving to a script and run that script, or just remove the `if`-clause:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. OP is using REPL. I would like to add the caution that OP should work on Python fundamentals (`return` vs. `print`) before jumping in to `multiprocessing`. Python `multiprocessing` can act in unexpected ways and you need to have a firm grasp on things before tackling it.

Comment: Works when run from file, but still not from interactive interpreter.

Comment: Then my answer is correct and you can go read about the use of `__name__` in the link I provided.

Comment: Do you mean that your example (without if-clause) should work as such in IDLE?

Comment: You did not mention IDLE in the question previously. But no, IDLE seems to be a bit of a special case. It does however work as expected from the normal "python" command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

At first there is a large difference between returning and printing. Your code has no `return` so it is only printing.

An other process has a different `stdout` associated to which printed text will go. You will not see it until you explicitly connect it to the `stdout` of the main process or process it in an other way. The `subprocess.Popen()` allows to do that, `multiprocessing.Process()` does not as far as I am aware.

Comment: "You will not see it until you explicitly connect it to the stdout of the main process or process it in an other way. " This is wrong. The example in this question is the same as the official example in the `multiprocessing` documentation which does the same thing. All proceses will use the same normal `stdout`.